# C++ operator new returns unexpected value

Tags: c++

I am working with conversion operators and I an error just popped out of nowhere. `C` class is derived from `B` and has no relation with class `A`, however, debugger shows that when doing `C* val1  = new C` val1 is showed as `C* {A<B>}`. It also produces an error because that `A` in the `C*` pointer has a size of an unreasonable size (it gives a different size each time it is executed so I just suppose it gets a number from another application).

````
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename widget_type>
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<widget_type*> value;

    virtual ~A() {}

    void Add(widget_type* val)
    {
        value.push_back(val);
    }
    template<typename return_type>
    operator A<return_type>()
    {
        unsigned int size = this->value.size();
        std::vector<return_type*> return_value;
        return_value.reserve(size);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            return_value[i] = dynamic_cast<return_type*>(this->value[i]);
        }
        A<return_type> target;
        target.value = return_value;
        return target;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "C CALL\n";
    }
};

class D : public B
{

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start!\n";
    A<C> source;
    C* val1 = new C;
    source.Add(val1);
    A<B> target = source;
    A<B>* target2 = dynamic_cast<A<B>*>(&source);

    std::cout << "END\n";
}```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        return_value[i] = dynamic_cast<return_type*>(this->value[i]);
    }
```

You are invoking undefined behaviour by accessing `return_value[i]` on an empty vector.

Comment: hmm, but ```return_value.reserve(size)``` already reserves the enough space for that vector. Should I use ```return_value.resize(size)``` then?

Comment: @Salty28: Yes, you should do that. The behaviour otherwise is undefined as per this answer.

Comment: @Salty27 `reserve()` only allocates memory for the underlying array, it does not create objects in that array. Accessing `return_value[i]` requires fully constructed objects. The valid range of `operator[]` is `[0..size)`, not `[0..capacity)` like you are expecting.  So yes, use `resize()` instead of `reserve()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks a lot for explaining that. Then when should ```reserve()``` be used? Should I create a separate question?

Comment: @Salty27 yes, that would warrant a new question. Though I'm sure you can find plenty of duplicates already posted.